# Combine save / update actions in a controller?

Tags: grails

I am wondering if there is any cleaner way to write the controller code?

Normally when doing a save you create a new object from the params and validate/save the object.

```
    def order = new Order(params)
    if(order.validate() && order.save())
```

When doing an update action you get the object from the DB and the bind the params/validate/save.

```
    def order = Order.get(params.id)
    order.properties = params
    if(order.validate() && order.save()) {
```

Is there a way in which the save and update can be combined in a saveOrUpdate action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def saveOrUpdate = {
    flash.errors = []
    def order = params.id ? Order.get(params.id as Long) : null

    if (order) {
        bindData (order, params)
    } else {
        order = new Order(params)
    }

    if (!order.hasErrors() && order.save(flush: true)) {
        flash.message = (params.id ? message(code: 'object.updated.message') : message(code: 'object.created.message'))
        return redirect(action: "edit", model:[bean:order])
    } else {
        flash.errors << message(code: 'errors.save.object')
        return render(view: 'edit', model: [bean: order])
    }
}
```